# I am trying to launch a proxy server using custom proxies

Tags: python, sockets, python-requests

I am trying to launch chrome and do some web scraping but I don't know how to launch a proxy server using a custom proxy.

Here is the proxy: `ultra.marsproxies.com:44443:mr5288luJd:MgC2yzBIYf_country-de_session-onsf0lci`

Comment: As currently asked this question seems to be off-topic and also have the wrong tags. According to the tags this has something to do with python, requests and sockets - but the text of the question asks about Chrome. Configuring Chrome is not a programming question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.